# Creating blob (Oracle) returns "Method is not implemented by JDBC driver" (Jboss eap 5.1)

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, jboss, blob

I have
Blob bl = pstmt.getConnection().createBlob(); a code where it is trying to create/save a blob in Oracle:
returning the following error:
"Method is not implemented by JDBC driver"

That is the message I am getting, cant see more.

The application is in a Jboss EAP 5.1 with the following changes:
- jboss-common-jdbc-wrapper.jar --changed--> jboss-as-connector-6.1.0.final-jboss-common-jdbc-wrapper.jar
- server/all/lib/ojdbc6.jar

Which can be the problem?

---

Comment: Check for type mismatch between code and actual column

Comment: Which Oracle JDBC driver version are you using (and no, ojdbc6 is not a version). Posting the full stacktrace of the exception would also be helpful to pinpoint the cause.

Comment: For jboss-eap, check the correct ojdbc jar version under the path "modules\system\layers\base\com\oracle\main". changing the correct ojdbc jar for the database fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

This is a JDBC version / JDBC driver mismatch.  The `Connection.createBlob()` method is added in JDBC level 4, and the ojdbc6 JAR is supposed to support that: see [Support for JDBC 4](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/java.111/b31224/jdbcvers.htm#BCFFIFAD) in the Oracle "Database JDBC Developer's Guide and Reference" document (Oracle 11g release 1).

You say you are using ojdbc6.jar, but maybe it is an older version, or maybe there is a different Oracle driver JAR ahead of it on the runtime classpath.

Comment: I think it is impossible to tell without a specific driver version (ojdbc6 is not a version), on top of that the problem could actually be with the jdbc-wrapper driver instead of the Oracle JDBC driver.

Comment: As far as I can tell, the wrapper passes the createBlob call through to the wrapped connection.