# primary key as like char

Tags: java, jdbc

I have a table as a primary key a char (1) in the sql server using the jtds driver.

```
public class Situacao{
   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
   @Column(name = "cod_sit_pedi_aval")  
   private Character codSitPediAval;
}

public class Pedido{
  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "cod_sit_pedi_aval")
  private Situacao situacao;
}
```

But when I update, I get the following error:

```
IJ031042: Method is not implemented by JDBC driver
Caused by: java.lang.AbstractMethodError 
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.JtdsPreparedStatement.setCharacterStream(JtdsPreparedStatement.java:1274) 
    at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrappedPreparedStatement.setCharacterStream(WrappedPreparedStatement.java:1466)
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: duplicate? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30190218/creating-blob-oracle-returns-method-is-not-implemented-by-jdbc-driver-jboss

Comment: I did not understand your question

Comment: look at the answer there .. maybe its your problem .. they talk about incombatible versions ...

Comment: I'm already using the latest version of the driver which is 1.3.1. 
I need some way around this

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there is [bug](https://sourceforge.net/p/jtds/bugs/703/) already assigned for these specific cases, as like the one that you've mentioned in your question.

One of the possible solutions that even was mentioned on the forums was to switch to `sqljdbc4` instead of the `jTDS` version of the `JDBC` jar that you're using currently. There is no version available with this patch, though this is not a tough bit to crack but can be unreliable!

Hope that this answers your question well!

Comment: unfortunately I can not change the driver, so it is so difficult to solve this problem

Comment: Looks line @Felipej.lemos